# refer textarea when submit the form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have number of forms in my page (lets says 2). I want to submit them using Ajax.

How do I "tell" my script to refer only to the input field in the form I submitted (and not to the other one)?

Can I do this:

```
form_data.$(this).parents('form').$("#textArea").val();
```

Instead of:

```
form_data.append('comment[text]',  $("#textArea").val());
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" id="addCommentForm4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' value='<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>' id="pageName" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' value='4' id="refID" />

    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment[text]" id="textArea"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='multi form-control' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="files"/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit" refID='4'>Send</a>

</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" id="addCommentForm5" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' value='<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>' id="pageName" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' value='5' id="refID" />

    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment[text]" id="textArea"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='multi form-control' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' id="files"/>
    <a class="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit" refID='5'>Send</a>

</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {

        var element = $(this);
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
        alert(refID);

        var file_data = $('#addCommentForm'+refID+' #files').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file[]', file_data);
        var files_data =  form_data;

        var act = 'add';
        form_data.append('act', act);
        form_data.append('comment[text]',  $("#textArea").val());   
        form_data.append('comment[pageName]',  $("#pageName").val());   
        form_data.append('comment[refID]',  $("#refID").val()); 


        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajax/addComment.php",

               dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
               cache: false,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,  

               data: form_data,
               success: function(data)
               {
                    $('#commentsBox').html(data);
               }

             });

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is remove the duplicate `id` attributes - they should be unique within the context of the page. Use common classes to identify the fields instead, and traverse from the submitted `form` element to retrieve their values.

Also note that it is better practice to hook to the `submit` event of the `form`, instead of the `click` of the submit button. This also makes your issue moot. Try this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' class="pagename-field" value='<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' class="refid-field" value='4' />

    <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='multi form-control comment-field' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
    <a class="btn btn-primary submit">Send</a>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' class="pagename-field" value='<?PHP echo $_GET['page'] ?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' class="refid-field" value='4' />

    <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='multi form-control comment-field' maxlength='1' accept='gif|jpg|png|bmp' />
    <a class="btn btn-primary submit">Send</a>
</form>
```

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission, as you're using AJAX

    var $form = $(this);
    var form_data = new FormData();       
    form_data.append('act', 'add');
    form_data.append('comment[text]',  $form.find('.comment-field').val());   
    form_data.append('comment[pageName]',  $form.find('.pagename-field').val());   
    form_data.append('comment[refID]',  $form.find('.refid-field').val());            
    form_data.append('file[]', $form.find('.file-field').prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/addComment.php",
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,  
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#commentsBox').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, I would suggest returning JSON instead of plain text from `addComment.php`. It's much more extensible in the future, should you need to change the returned data.

Comment: what do i need to change in order to use JSON as you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$("#textArea").val()` do either of the below:

- `$("#addCommentForm" + refID + " #textArea").val();`
- `$("#addCommentForm" + refID).find("#textArea").val();`
- `$("#textArea",$("#addCommentForm" + refID)).val()`